# How do we replace multiple rows of data with the mean of those rows for every change in the other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with a column 'Medals' containing either Gold, Silver or Bronze.
There is a height column and a year column. It looks something like this -

```
Medal   Year    Height      0
Bronze  1896    -2.352063   1
Bronze  1896    -0.435173   1
Bronze  1896    0.220606    1
Bronze  1896    0.304680    1
Bronze  1896    0.607347    1
Bronze  1900    -1.847618   1
Bronze  1900    -1.410432   1
Bronze  1900    -0.334284   1
Bronze  1900    -0.182950   1
Bronze  1900    -0.031617   3
Bronze  1900    0.136532    2
Silver  2016    1.078162    9
Silver  2016    1.179051    2
Silver  2016    1.279940    1
Silver  2016    1.380829    4
Silver  2016    1.481718    3
Silver  2016    1.582607    3
Silver  2016    1.683495    8
Silver  2016    1.784384    4
Silver  2016    1.885273    3
Silver  2016    2.087051    1
Silver  2016    2.187940    1
Silver  2016    2.288829    1
Silver  2016    2.591496    1
Silver  2016    2.692385    1
Silver  2016    2.995052    1
```

What I want is simple -

```
Medal   Year    Height      
Bronze  1896    [Mean of heights having Bronze and 1896] 
Bronze  1896    [Mean of heights having Bronze and 1900]   
Bronze  1896    [Mean of heights having Silver and 2016]
```

Also [0] column represents the frequency. So we have to multiply it with the height before calculating mean.

I tried using `np.einsum` but I wasn't able to make it work for my case. There are a few similar questions but none of the answers suit my requirements.
Any hints would be helpful.

PS: I have normalized the heights column and hence the negative values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to create 2 series via Pandas `groupby` and divide one by the other:

```
group_cols = ['Medal', 'Year']
observations = df.groupby(group_cols)[0].sum()
total_height = df.assign(total=df['Height']*df[0]).groupby(group_cols)['total'].sum()

res = total_height / observations

print(res.reset_index())

    Medal  Year         0
0  Bronze  1896 -0.330921
1  Bronze  1900 -0.399675
2  Silver  2016  1.608415
```

More succinctly (thanks @piRSquared):

```
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'Count'})

res = df.assign(Total=df['Height']*df['Count'])\
        .groupby(['Medal', 'Year']).sum()\
        .eval('Total / Count')\
        .rename('Mean').reset_index()

print(res)

    Medal  Year      Mean
0  Bronze  1896 -0.330921
1  Bronze  1900 -0.399675
2  Silver  2016  1.608415
```

Comment: My reconfigured version of this `df.rename(columns={'0': 'Hz'}).assign(Height=lambda d: d.Height * d.Hz).groupby(['Medal', 'Year']).sum().eval('Height / Hz')`

Comment: @piRSquared, Clever, I like the `eval`, not so much the `lambda` :).

Answer (score 3):

#### `pandas.Index.repeat`

- Use `'0'` column to repeat the `index`
- Use `loc` to reindex by it
- Then `groupby`

---

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['0'])].groupby(['Medal', 'Year'])['Height'].mean()

Medal   Year
Bronze  1896   -0.330921
        1900   -0.399675
Silver  2016    1.608415
Name: Height, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is nice. But I suspect more memory intensive?

Comment: Yes. I agree @jpp